# app se cierra al cabo de un rato

Tags: android

quiero poner marker en mi mapa que los lee de una base de dato, mysql  para esto ocupo json, y todo funciona bien me muestra los marcadores en mapa y tambien se mueve , pero al cabo de un rato la aplicacion se cierra sola mas menos despues de 5 minutos. este es mi codigo llevo 2 meses con este error, les cuento que estoy recien aprendiendo y mucho de lo que tengo lo he ido sacando de internet, de ante mano muchas gracias y ayudenme con peritas y manzana.

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
String direccion, mensaje1;
private Marker marcador;
double lat, longi;
private final String TAG = "FragmentMaps";
double lat1, lon1, latD, lonD;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
//JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
String latM;
String lonM;
public static final int MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 15000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    final GoogleMap finalGoogleMap = googleMap;
    miUbicacion();
}

private void locationStar() {
    LocationManager mlocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final boolean gpsEnable = mlocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (!gpsEnable) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,},
                1000);
    }
        return;
}

public void setLocation(Location loc) {
}

private boolean agregarMarcador(double lat, double longi) {
    LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, longi);
    CameraUpdate MiUbicacion1 = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 17);
    if (marcador != null) {
        marcador.remove();
    }
    marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordenadas)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)
                    ));
    mMap.animateCamera(MiUbicacion1);

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest("http://www.rendidor.cl/colect/back/busca_movil_activos.php",
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            //editM.setText(jsonObject.getString("cu_usuario"));
                            latM = (String) (jsonObject.getString("cu_latitud"));
                            lonM = (String) (jsonObject.getString("cu_longitud"));

                            latD = Double.parseDouble(latM);
                            lonD = Double.parseDouble(lonM);
                            universal.GpsLat = latD;
                            universal.GpsLong = lonD;

                            LatLng latLngM = new LatLng(latD, lonD);

                            marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLngM)
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE))
                                    .title((jsonObject.getString("cu_usuario")))
                            );

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                }

            }, new com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Error de Conexion", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    requestQueue = (RequestQueue) Volley.newRequestQueue(MapsActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    return false;
}

private void actualizarUbicacion(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        longi = location.getLongitude();
        agregarMarcador(lat,longi);
    }
}

LocationListener mlocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mMap.clear();

        actualizarUbicacion(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        mensaje1 = ("gps Activado");
        mensaje();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        mensaje1 = ("Gps desactivado");
        locationStar();
        mensaje();
    }
};

private static int PETICION_PERMISIO_LOCALIZACION = 101;

private void miUbicacion() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                 new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PETICION_PERMISIO_LOCALIZACION);
        return;
    }
    else {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,0,mlocationListener);
        actualizarUbicacion(location);
    }
}
public void mensaje(){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, mensaje1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
}
```

}

///////////////7 aqui el LOGCAT
19-11-07 21:29:58.335 15883-15896/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=252KB, data=187KB
2019-11-07 21:29:58.337 15883-15896/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=252KB, data=187KB
2019-11-07 21:29:58.337 15883-15896/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
2019-11-07 21:30:15.308 15883-15896/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=506KB, data=355KB
2019-11-07 21:30:15.312 15883-15896/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=414KB, data=272KB
2019-11-07 21:30:19.060 15883-15896/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=506KB, data=362KB
2019-11-07 21:30:19.067 15883-15896/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=506KB, data=362KB
2019-11-07 21:30:19.067 15883-15896/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 2MB
2019-11-07 21:33:05.308 15883-15903/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 57912(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 48(960KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 6MB/12MB, paused 1.371ms total 101.269ms
2019-11-07 21:33:53.215 15883-15903/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 56281(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 46(920KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 6MB/13MB, paused 1.734ms total 105.839ms
2019-11-07 21:34:05.197 15883-15903/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 61900(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 48(960KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 6MB/13MB, paused 1.154ms total 111.819ms
2019-11-07 21:34:20.328 15883-15903/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 62132(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 46(920KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 6MB/13MB, paused 1.530ms total 114.069ms
2019-11-07 21:34:24.155 15883-15883/tiato.com.mapas W/zygote: Large object allocation failed: Failed anonymous mmap(0x0, 20480, 0x3, 0x2, 96, 0): Operation not permitted. See process maps in the log.
2019-11-07 21:34:24.155 15883-15883/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2019-11-07 21:34:24.155 15883-15883/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2019-11-07 21:34:24.270 15883-15883/tiato.com.mapas I/zygote: Alloc concurrent copying GC freed 20050(1079KB) AllocSpace objects, 14(280KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 6MB/13MB, paused 1.348ms total 115.204ms

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

2019-11-07 21:34:25.084 15883-15883/tiato.com.mapas A/libc: failed to allocate TLS
2019-11-07 21:34:25.089 15883-15883/tiato.com.mapas A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 15883 (tiato.com.mapas)
2019-11-07 21:34:30.202 15883-17276/tiato.com.mapas A/libc: failed to allocate TLS

Comment: El mensaje de error LogCat, puede ser la diferencia entre tomar unos segundos para corregir un detalle o tomar una semana.

Comment: YA PUSE EL LOGCAT SOLICITADO GRACIAS JORGE